# adding a css class to a jquery variable

Tags: jquery, css

I'm struggling to adding a css class to a jquery variable. I'm creating a chatbot and as i'm passing the user string from a html input box i would like it to take on an extra class such that it looks like a bubble a la whatsapp. currently it reads 
var userMessage = $('#textbox').val();

I have tried .addClass('.userBubble'); but that didn't work and the console said that .addClass(); is not a function. Help greatly appreciated

Comment: Share working snippet

Comment: are you trying to do `userMessage.addClass()`? in which case it won't work.  `userMessage` is just a string variable. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but try  `$('#textbox').addClass('userBubble')` (remove the dot before the class name)

Comment: Can you please paste your code here, and did you add jquery files correctly. `addClass()` doesn't work on value as @adiga said.

Comment: Plenty of examples [in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/). You call `addClass` on a jQuery object. You pass it a **class name** (or several separated with spaces), not a selector (no leading `.`). So you'd create an element (perhaps a `div`) wrapped in a jQuery object, add `userMessage` to it as text, add the class to it, and append it somewhere. Loosely: `$("<div>").text(userMessage).addClass("userBubble").appendTo(document.body);`

Comment: Use -> `addClass('userBubble');` not `addClass('.userBubble');`

Comment: @bhansa it's not a prblem with jQuery reference because I'm assuming `$('#textbox').val()` is already working

Comment: @adiga but I guess userMessage won't have addClass function.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that might be wrong with your code.

1. You need to pass a css class name not a css class selector: `"className"` and 
   not `".className"`.
2. `addClass` works on jQuery objects not on other objects.

Basic example:

```js
$('#myelement').on('click', function(){
  $('#otherelement').addClass('colored');
});
```

```css
.colored{
  color: #ccc;
  background-color: #333;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myelement">Click Me</div>
<div id="otherelement">Some text...</div>
```